# How to keep detecting if button is pressed in JInput?

Tags: java, jinput

Button and HAT presses in JInput is based on events, meaning if I press Button 1, it will only fire once while I'm holding it down and once again when I release the button. I want to make it so that if I have the button held down, it will still keep calling the method I assigned to it. How do I do this>

Comment: If you have control over the main loop, set up a flag that when true, will call you method.  If you don't set up a timer that can be triggered on a regular basis until you release the button

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm kinda new to Java itself.

Comment: It would depend on how you've setup you code?  Are you using a main loop of some kind or not?

Comment: No, I don't. I'm kinda interested in the timer approach.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I did some research and eventually ended up with the following which solved it for me:

```
    myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }, 50, 50);
```

Then I call the following on another method when I need to stop the timer.

```
    myTimer.cancel;
    myTimer.purge;
```